# How to make footer static in Zen theme using zen grid

Tags: theming

I used a Zen theme as my base theme which enables me to use zengrid to define my custom layout.  The thing is every time I move away from front page, the footer custom layout is disappeared, it only shown in the front page.

How do I make it static so it show up on every page and not just the front page.?